# Package java.time does not exist, jdk1.8

Tags: java, netbeans

Well I just started working on codenameone I have a quite decent experience with Java. My code is all good, got no problems although while compiling I get this: error: package java.time does not exist import java.time.LocalDate;

Yes I know LocalDate was introduced in Java8 so my [netbeans is set on Java8 also my project.](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk8.html)
Note that I'm using Lambda Expresions and streams in the project without any problem.

What can cause this?

Update: This bug is not only with my machine, tested on several machines that run Java 8 correctly (java.time is seen) with JavaFX application or simple Java applications still have same bug with Codenameone projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came to a fair answer. Codenameone is not compatible with all java 8 features. See [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans you need to choose Java8 in order to use Java8 features. It is not enough to only have Java8 installed.

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel its is all about project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Find **Java Dependencies -> JDK 1.8 (Default) -> rt.jar** at your *Projects* frame in Netbeans. You should see `java.time` package under `rt.jar`. If not, there is something wrong with your Netbeans or JDK installation.

You can also check **Tools -> Java Platform** to make sure Java 8 is correctly configured with Netbeans.