# Java.time not found - JDK 13

Tags: java, maven, java-time, java.time.instant, java-13

[compilation snap-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjAsS.jpg) [compilation snap-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K2Yp.jpg) I'm trying to upgrade my project from java 1.8 to version 13.0.2. There were some unsupported functions which I removed. Unfortunately **toInstant()** is one of them.
My project uses it in a java module like this:

```
Date date = format.parse(inputDate);
finalDate = date.toInstant().toString();
```

Now I'm not able to compile the code with toInstant() with JDK 13 because it says 'Symbol not found' and compilation error occurs:

```
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method toInstant()
[ERROR]   location: variable date of type java.util.Date
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

So I looked out for several code replacements for toInstant() and decided to get rid of it by using few functions from java.time. But java.time is not found during compilation:

```
package java.time does not exist
```

Does this denote that something is wrong with my JDK set up ? I'm not facing any other issues apart from this one issue.
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX2c9.png)

Compilation errors:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project XXXX: Compilation failure
/C:/utilities1/New folder/XXXX/src/main/java/com/XXXX/test.java:[167,52] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method toInstant()
  location: variable date of type java.util.Date

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/C:/utilities1/New folder/XXXX/src/main/java/com/XXXX/test.java:[167,52] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method toInstant()
  location: variable date of type java.util.Date

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tscsoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>TSCWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>TSC Web Application</name>
    <description>The TSC Web Application</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <web-context-root>C:\Web\dev</web-context-root>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>3.6.3</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>3.6.3</maven.compiler.source>        
        <maven.compiler.release>7</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>7</release>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${web-context-root}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ext-release-local</id>
            <url>http://erp.maven.srb-es.com:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.speech</groupId>
            <artifactId>ATTJSAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons.discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons.fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons.lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.enterprisedt.net.ftp</groupId>
            <artifactId>edtftpj</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie.text</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>1.02b</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie.text.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>iTextXML</artifactId>
            <version>1.02b</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-beta-9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.security.cert</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcert</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jrefinery</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.jfree.chart</groupId>
               <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.19</version>
               <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
               <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.23</version>
               <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.net</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnet</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.net.ssl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsse</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.makarosoft.monitor.agent</groupId>
            <artifactId>MonitorAgentClient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pf</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pv.jfcx</groupId>
            <artifactId>pvxedits</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stax</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tscsoftware.terminalEmulator.ticket</groupId>
            <artifactId>teTicket</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tscsoftware.tmqnotifier</groupId>
            <artifactId>TMQNotifier</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tscsoftware.terminalEmulator</groupId>
            <artifactId>tsc_ate</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-aegis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-attributes</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>commons-attributes-api</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>qdox</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>qdox</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-java5</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xfire</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>xfire-jsr181-api</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>xfire-jaxb2</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>xfire-generator</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>xfire-xmlbeans</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <classifier>M1</classifier>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>xfire-xmlbeans</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlcommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.04</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xml.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.borland.jbcl.layout</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>jsch</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId> 
            <version>0.1.51</version> 
            <scope>compile</scope> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2-Atrieve</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please [edit] your question to show the line that is giving that error. That package is there from Java 8. Also please show how you're compiling your program.

Comment: Also, `Date` in Java 13 still has a [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()) method (if we're talking about a `java.util.Date` and not some other type) which has been there since java 8 as well. I'm starting to wonder whether you're actually building this with an *older* version of java instead.

Comment: Hi @FedericoklezCulloca, I have edited the question and included the error snapshot. Thanks !

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531218/package-java-time-does-not-exist-jdk1-8

Comment: @VickySivarajan the compilation output should show `JAVA_HOME` at the top. What's its value?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I can't find java_home in the output but I see these: (note: I configured it in environment variable too)

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Added POM @user16320675

Comment: @VickySivarajan `<maven.compiler.release>7</maven.compiler.release>` this doesn't look right.

Comment: @VickySivarajan take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723533/how-do-you-specify-the-java-compiler-version-in-a-pom-xml-file)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I fixed my POM using the references you provided and the compilation errors got resolved.